# SQL server deny access to public role

Tags: sql-server, database

I am using SQL server 2017
I have a login
with access to a database .
Login also has public role by default

I do not want public role to access the database, so i denied all permission to public , but i gave grant all to the login

Now the user is also not able to select database.

What i want is user to have all access to database but not public role since everyone has it

i also tried to revoke it since deny blocks every one

### query 1 : this query shows public has privleges

```
SELECT DISTINCT pr.principal_id, pr.name AS [UserName], 
    pr.type_desc AS [User_or_Role], 
    pr.authentication_type_desc AS [Auth_Type], pe.state_desc,
    pe.permission_name, pe.class_desc, o.[name] AS 'Object' 
FROM sys.database_principals AS pr 
JOIN sys.database_permissions AS pe 
    ON pe.grantee_principal_id = pr.principal_id
LEFT JOIN sys.objects AS o on (o.object_id = pe.major_id);
```

query2:

```
REVOKE select,DELETE,insert,execute,references on database::Foo to public cascade ;
```

even after revoking query1 output  still shows up with public having grant access to select/insert  and all

Comment: `DENY` > `GRANT` If you have explicitly denied the `public` role permission *no one* can do that, unless you remove them from the `public` role. By default, the `public` role can't do anything anyway; if you have given the role explicit permission, `REVOKE` them.

Comment: I revoked it with my query2 , but then i run my query 1 and is still see that public has grant 
UserName User_or_Role Auth_Type state_desc permission_name class_desc Object
public DATABASE_ROLE NONE GRANT UPDATE OBJECT_OR_COLUMN Orders

Comment: Did you *try* as a `USER` that is only a member of the `public` role to `SELECT` from one of these tables?

Comment: "I do not want public role to access the database" - database roles don't access a database, users do. Roles have user members who inherit the granted and denied permissions granted to the role. Public is a special role where all database users are implicitly members. If you don't want a user to access the database, don't add them as a database user.

Comment: i tried a user with only public role , i was not able to access . but not sure why query 1 still returns output with public grant to the database which confused me . 
UserName User_or_Role Auth_Type state_desc permission_name class_desc
public DATABASE_ROLE NONE GRANT DELETE OBJECT_OR_COLUMN
public DATABASE_ROLE NONE GRANT DELETE OBJECT_OR_COLUMN
public DATABASE_ROLE NONE GRANT DELETE OBJECT_OR_COLUMN

Answer (score 0):

**It is better not to touch the default public role accesses.**

**This may restrict access to the database. Please be careful.**

Users cannot be removed from the public role but permissions can be revoked.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver15

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver15

This script revoke accesses from public role on a specific database

```
USE Foo;--Your database
GO
IF NOT (OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#TMP') IS NULL)
DROP TABLE #TMP
GO
SELECT * INTO #TMP
FROM (
    SELECT 
        obj.name AS [ObjectName],
        schema_name(obj.schema_id) AS [ObjectSchema],
        CASE WHEN (prmssn.class=4 or prmssn.class=101 ) THEN CASE (SELECT oc.type FROM sys.database_principals AS oc WHERE oc.principal_id = prmssn.major_id) WHEN 'R' THEN CASE prmssn.class WHEN 4 THEN 201 ELSE 301 END WHEN 'A' THEN 202 ELSE CASE prmssn.class WHEN 4 THEN 200 ELSE 101 END END ELSE prmssn.class END AS [ObjectClass],
        obj.type AS [ObjectType],
        0 AS [IsTableType]
    FROM
        sys.database_permissions AS prmssn
        INNER JOIN sys.all_objects AS obj ON obj.object_id = prmssn.major_id and prmssn.class = 1
        INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS grantee_principal ON grantee_principal.principal_id = prmssn.grantee_principal_id
    WHERE
    (grantee_principal.name='Public')
    UNION
    SELECT
        obj.name AS [ObjectName],
        null AS [ObjectSchema],
        CASE WHEN (prmssn.class=4 or prmssn.class=101 ) THEN CASE (SELECT oc.type FROM sys.database_principals AS oc WHERE oc.principal_id = prmssn.major_id) WHEN 'R' THEN CASE prmssn.class WHEN 4 THEN 201 ELSE 301 END WHEN 'A' THEN 202 ELSE CASE prmssn.class WHEN 4 THEN 200 ELSE 101 END END ELSE prmssn.class END AS [ObjectClass],
        null AS [ObjectType],
        0 AS [IsTableType]
    FROM
        sys.database_permissions AS prmssn
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS obj ON obj.schema_id = prmssn.major_id and prmssn.class = 3
        INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS grantee_principal ON grantee_principal.principal_id = prmssn.grantee_principal_id
    WHERE
    (grantee_principal.name='Public')
    UNION
    SELECT
        obj.name AS [ObjectName],
        null AS [ObjectSchema],
        CASE WHEN (prmssn.class=4 or prmssn.class=101 ) THEN CASE (SELECT oc.type FROM sys.database_principals AS oc WHERE oc.principal_id = prmssn.major_id) WHEN 'R' THEN CASE prmssn.class WHEN 4 THEN 201 ELSE 301 END WHEN 'A' THEN 202 ELSE CASE prmssn.class WHEN 4 THEN 200 ELSE 101 END END ELSE prmssn.class END AS [ObjectClass],
        null AS [ObjectType],
        0 AS [IsTableType]
    FROM
        sys.database_permissions AS prmssn
        INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS obj ON obj.principal_id = prmssn.major_id and prmssn.class = 4
        INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS grantee_principal ON grantee_principal.principal_id = prmssn.grantee_principal_id
    WHERE
    (grantee_principal.name='Public')
    UNION
    SELECT
        obj.name AS [ObjectName],
        null AS [ObjectSchema],
        CASE WHEN (prmssn.class=4 or prmssn.class=101 ) THEN CASE (SELECT oc.type FROM sys.database_principals AS oc WHERE oc.principal_id = prmssn.major_id) WHEN 'R' THEN CASE prmssn.class WHEN 4 THEN 201 ELSE 301 END WHEN 'A' THEN 202 ELSE CASE prmssn.class WHEN 4 THEN 200 ELSE 101 END END ELSE prmssn.class END AS [ObjectClass],
        null AS [ObjectType],
        0 AS [IsTableType]
    FROM
        sys.database_permissions AS prmssn
        INNER JOIN sys.assemblies AS obj ON obj.assembly_id = prmssn.major_id and prmssn.class = 5
        INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS grantee_principal ON grantee_principal.principal_id = prmssn.grantee_principal_id
    WHERE
    (grantee_principal.name='Public')
    UNION
    SELECT
        obj.name AS [ObjectName],
        SCHEMA_NAME(obj.schema_id) AS [ObjectSchema],
        CASE WHEN (prmssn.class=4 or prmssn.class=101 ) THEN CASE (SELECT oc.type FROM sys.database_principals AS oc WHERE oc.principal_id = prmssn.major_id) WHEN 'R' THEN CASE prmssn.class WHEN 4 THEN 201 ELSE 301 END WHEN 'A' THEN 202 ELSE CASE prmssn.class WHEN 4 THEN 200 ELSE 101 END END ELSE prmssn.class END AS [ObjectClass],
        null AS [ObjectType],
        obj.is_table_type AS [IsTableType]
    FROM
        sys.database_permissions AS prmssn
        INNER JOIN sys.types AS obj ON obj.user_type_id = prmssn.major_id and prmssn.class = 6
        INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS grantee_principal ON grantee_principal.principal_id = prmssn.grantee_principal_id
    WHERE
    (grantee_principal.name='Public')
    UNION
    SELECT
        obj.name AS [ObjectName],
        null AS [ObjectSchema],
        CASE WHEN (prmssn.class=4 or prmssn.class=101 ) THEN CASE (SELECT oc.type FROM sys.database_principals AS oc WHERE oc.principal_id = prmssn.major_id) WHEN 'R' THEN CASE prmssn.class WHEN 4 THEN 201 ELSE 301 END WHEN 'A' THEN 202 ELSE CASE prmssn.class WHEN 4 THEN 200 ELSE 101 END END ELSE prmssn.class END AS [ObjectClass],
        null AS [ObjectType],
        0 AS [IsTableType]
    FROM
        sys.database_permissions AS prmssn
        INNER JOIN sys.fulltext_catalogs AS obj ON obj.fulltext_catalog_id = prmssn.major_id and prmssn.class = 23
        INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS grantee_principal ON grantee_principal.principal_id = prmssn.grantee_principal_id
    WHERE
    (grantee_principal.name='Public')
)T
GO
SELECT 'REVOKE ALL ON '+'[' + ObjectSchema + ']' +'.[' + ObjectName+ ']' + ' To Public
GO'
FROM #TMP
GO
```

Run the created query.